# loop repeating comparing arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code and I want to compare the data that came from db with the one user selects but it seems that the   `foreach($question_answers as  $answer){` 
 and `foreach ($user_answer as $key => $value) {` it is not good it is repeating for 4 times more, I need a way to compare `$user_answer` which is what user has selected request from the view, and the  `$answer['order']` the order comes from database.  So I need a loop or something to compare these two.. any help..? thank you.

```
foreach($questions as $question) {

  $question_answers = OrderingAnswer::where('question_id', $question->id)
                    ->where('deleted',0)
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
  $users_answers = $request->except('_token', 'test_id');

  $user_answer = $users_answers[ $question->id];

  //  $user_answer ---> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 )
  foreach ($question_answers as  $answer) {
    //$answer['order'] ---> 1

    foreach ($user_answer as $key => $value) {
      if ($answer['order'] == $value ) {
        echo "ok ===>" .$value . "<br>" ;

      } else {
        echo "no   -------------------------------- >".$value  . "<br>" ;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you post 2 of these array samples - $question_answers  and $user_answer  and 3rd expected result format

Comment: $question_answers has this result if I do it with dd, array:4 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 251
    "question_id" => 242
    "text" => "pytja 1"
    "order" => 1
    "deleted" => 0
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▶]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
]     and $user_answer  has this  $user_answer ---> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 ),  and I want the order of $user_answer for ex 1 to be == with what is comming from db and to echo true otherwise I want to display as wrong that question, so one answer not in correct order the question is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this - it is working perfect. (This question was really intresting)

Here basically i am comparing multidimensional array value to a single dimensional array value. it will just give you array of matched results.

```
<?php
$question_answers= array(
        array("id"=>251,'question_id'=>242,'order'=>1),
        array("id"=>252,'question_id'=>243,'order'=>2)
    );
$user_answers = array(1,4,3,2);

// you can just use this part
$question_answers = array_filter($question_answers, function($arr) use ($user_answers) {
    return in_array($arr['order'], $user_answers); 
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($question_answers);
?>
```